# 受信メール本文の容量を、ヘッダから確認することは出来ますか？

Tags: mail, sendmail

**cron経由で送信した(添付ファイルなしの)メールを「Yahoo!メール」で受信すると、全文表示することが出来ません。**

> ロード中...

・恐らく、メール本文の容量が制限を超えているからだと思うのですが、そのことを確かめる方法はありますか？
・受信メール本文の容量を、「詳細ヘッダー」から確認することは出来ない？？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

詳細ヘッダーの中に表示される、`Content-Length` の数値を確認してください (単位： バイト)。

Comment: 確認できました。容量制限を超えていました